# Is there a standard way to get HTMLSelectElement from HTMLOptionElement?

Tags: javascript, html, web-standards

`HTMLSelectElement` currently provides `HTMLSelectElement.options` property to access all its options children regardless of `optgroup` in the way. But, the reverse is not known.

Currently, we need to traverse the element.

```js
let select;
let parent = target;
while (parent.parentElement) {
    if (parent.tagName === 'SELECT') {
        select = parent;
        break;
    }
    parent = parent.parentElement;
}
```

Is there a standard property or function to get HTMLSelectElement from HTMLOptionElement?
Or alternatively more efficient way apart from above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no property of HTMLOptionElement objects which gives you the associated select element.

The [`closest` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is a built-in method for searching the DOM in the manor that you have reimplemented though.

Note that an option element can belong to a select or to a datalist, so you might want to handle both possibilities in your search.

```
const control = option.closest('select, datalist')
```